# MediaStore.Audio retrieve list of all the directories that contain audios

Tags: android, audio, android-contentprovider, mediastore

I am trying to get a list of all the directories that contain audios. Here is the code that I am using:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection   = new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
    String   sortOrder    = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(context,MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projection,null,null,sortOrder);
    return cursorLoader;
}
```

`MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA` gives me a list of all the audio files with their filepaths (with their names appended).

`MediaStore.Audio.Media.Display_Name` gives me the titles of the files.

However, what I want is to run a query that returns me a list of all the folders/directories (their path, name, and count of audios) that contain audio content.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to retrieve a list of all the folders/directories containing `audios` from the device. By using the following code.

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection = new String[]{"COUNT(" + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + ") AS totalFiles",
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.PARENT,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME
            };

    String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + " = " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO +
            " OR "+ MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "=" + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO +
            ") GROUP BY (" + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.PARENT;

    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(context, MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), projection, selection, null, sortOrder);
    return cursorLoader;
}
```

This piece of code makes and returns a cursor that Queries content provider with all the files having `Media_Type` as `audio` plus count of audios in every folder plus the path and name of the folders.